# How to select array-kind data in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am no powershell developer. Therefore I need some help from the experts here around.
I´ve got a script which does all what I should, but now this extensions I am not able to implement.

Currently we read the following lines from a text file into the variable VmList:

```
LineA
LineB
LineC
LineD
```

These are handed over as follows:

```
$Lines = Get-Content $IniValue
```

Afterwards they are again in lines.

Now we want to remove the lines from the variable $Lines depending on the weekday.

For this purpose we changed the lines as follows:

```
LineA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
LineB,1,0,1,1,1,1,1
LineC,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
LineD,1,0,1,1,0,1,1
```

The `,1,1,1,1,1,1,1` stands for one weekday each. So the first number 1 stands for Monday, the second for Tuesday.

```
In line A, Tuesday is therefore set to 1
So in line B the Tuesday is set to 0
So in line C the Tuesday is set to 1
So in line D the Tuesday is set to 0
```

So on Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Saturday, Sunday the lines A,B,C,D in the variable $Lines should be kept.

Thus, for execution on Tuesday, lineB and lineD should be deleted from the variable $Lines.

Thus, for execution on Friday, only lineD is to be deleted from the variable $Lines.

After the rows have been cleaned up, the appended chains ,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 are to be deleted from all rows,

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Could you provide the complete code with an example text file?

Comment: You should remove the tag "shell" as it is confusing with UNIX shell.

Comment: @f6a4
I am sorry to say, but I don´t have any code, yet for this part... I mean except the described above:

Comment: @snwfdhmp ok, sorry... done...

Comment: @Dynamix thanks :) happy new year

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

# Generic list => better than array
[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$dayList = @()

# input file
$csvFile    = 'C:\test\weekdays.csv' 

# read file to generic list
$dayList    = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( $csvFile )

# get current weekday as a number
$currentDay = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__

# remove all records with 0 on current day
[void]$daylist.RemoveAll( {param($s) @($s -split ',')[$currentDay-1] -eq '0'}  )

# show list
$daylist
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a here string for demo.
In real life you would want to read this from file with `$Lines = Get-Content $IniValue`

```
$lines = @"
LineA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
LineB,1,0,1,1,1,1,1
LineC,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
LineD,1,0,1,1,0,1,1
"@ -split '\r?\n'

# get today's DayOfWeek
$today = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek

$lines | ForEach-Object {
    $parts = $_ -split ','
    # if Sunday, the index should be 7, otherwise the integer number of todays DayOfWeek
    $index = if ($today -eq 'Sunday') { 7 } else { [int]$today }
    if ([int]$parts[$index]) { $parts[0] }
}
```

Output for a Tuesday:

> ```
> LineA
> LineC
> ```

<sup>The reason for using `[int]` in `if ([int]$parts[$index])` is because the numbers split from the line may look like numbers, but in fact are strings `"0"` or `"1"`. Without the cast to integer, the if would check `if ("0")` or `if ("1")` and because both are not empty strings, the result will always be True.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.  Treat the input file as a csv, or make it a csv.  Today is tuesday.

```
$lines = import-csv $inivalue -header vm,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday
$day = (get-date).DayOfWeek
$lines | where { $_.$day -eq 1 } | ft


vm    monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
--    ------ ------- --------- -------- ------ -------- ------
LineA 1      1       1         1        1      1        1
LineC 1      1       1         1        1      1        1
```

And then to get the list of vm's:

```
$lines | where { $_.$day -eq 1 } | foreach vm


LineA
LineC
```

I was trying to do "where day", but it only works with int:

```
$lines | where { [int]$_.$day } | ft


vm    monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
--    ------ ------- --------- -------- ------ -------- ------
LineA 1      1       1         1        1      1        1
LineC 1      1       1         1        1      1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want the line name and the week data (all columns):

```
Get-Content File | Where {
    ($_ -split ',' | Select -Skip 1)[(Get-Date -uformat %u)-1] -eq 1}
```

`%u` is the format specifier for day of week number with Monday being 1. Since Sunday is 0, you have to take care of that special case. Getting index `[-1]` on the split, gets the last item in the split array, which is Sunday (`0-1`).

If you only want to return the first column of data, then [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59632156/11025476) is the simplest way to go.